# JS Create a table according to arrays

Tags: javascript, html

I try to create a table use 3 arrays values.
My arrays:

```
 Array1 = [{ "name": "a1", "value": "a1" }, { "name": "b1", "value": "b1" }];
 Array2 = [{ "name": "a2", "value": "a2", "array1": "a1" }, { "name": "b2", "value": "b2", "array1": "a1" }, { "name": "c2", "value": "c2", "array1": "b1" }];
 Array3 = [{ "name": "a3", "value": "a3", "array2": "a2" }, { "name": "b3", "value": "b3", "array2": "a2" }, { "name": "c3", "value": "c3", "array2": "a2" }, { "name": "d3", "value": "d3", "array2": "c2" }, { "name": "e3", "value": "e3", "array2": "c2" }];
```

I want that the result will be:
[image]

My code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script>
        window.onload = function x() {
            Array1 = [{ "name": "a1", "value": "a1" }, { "name": "b1", "value": "b1" }];
            Array2 = [{ "name": "a2", "value": "a2", "array1": "a1" }, { "name": "b2", "value": "b2", "array1": "a1" }, { "name": "c2", "value": "c2", "array1": "b1" }];
            Array3 = [{ "name": "a3", "value": "a3", "array2": "a2" }, { "name": "b3", "value": "b3", "array2": "a2" }, { "name": "c3", "value": "c3", "array2": "a2" }, { "name": "d3", "value": "d3", "array2": "c2" }, { "name": "e3", "value": "e3", "array2": "c2" }];

            //create the table

            var table = document.getElementById("table");
            var mainTR = document.createElement("TR");
            table.appendChild(mainTR);
            var numRow = 0;
            var numColumn = 0
            for (var i = 0; i < Array1.length; i++) {
                var a1 = Array1[i];
                var td1 = document.createElement("TD");
                td1.style.width = '20px';
                mainTR.appendChild(td1);

                var label = document.createElement('label')
                label.htmlFor = i;
                label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a1.name.toString()));
                var mybr = document.createElement('br');
                td1.appendChild(label);
                for (var j = 0, numColumn = 0; j < Array2.length; j++) {
                    var a2 = Array2[j];
                    if (a2.array1 == a1.name) {

                        if (i == 0) {
                            var tr = document.createElement("TR");
                            tr.id = "tr" + numRow;
                            numRow += 1;
                            table.appendChild(tr);
                        }
                        else {
                            var row = document.getElementById(("tr" + numColumn).toString());
                            //var tr = row.insertCell(i+1);
                            var tr = row.insertCell();
                        }


                        var td1 = document.createElement("TD");
                        td1.style.width = '20px';
                        tr.appendChild(td1);
                        var label = document.createElement('label')
                        label.htmlFor = i;
                        label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a2.name.toString()));
                        var mybr = document.createElement('br');
                        td1.appendChild(label);
                        numColumn += 1;
                    }
                    for (var z = 0, numColumn = 0; z < Array3.length; z++) {
                        var a3 = Array3[z];
                        if (a3.array2 == a2.name) {
                            if (i == 0) {
                                var tr = document.createElement("TR");
                                tr.id = "tr" + numRow;
                                numRow += 1;
                                table.appendChild(tr);
                            }
                            else {
                                var row = document.getElementById(("tr" + numColumn).toString());
                                //var tr = row.insertCell(i+1);
                                var tr = row.insertCell();
                            }


                            var td1 = document.createElement("TD");
                            td1.style.width = '20px';
                            tr.appendChild(td1);

                            var label = document.createElement('label')
                            label.htmlFor = i;
                            label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a3.name.toString()));
                            var mybr = document.createElement('br');
                            td1.appendChild(label);
                            numColumn += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
     <style>
            .table{
                border: 1px solid black;
                border-color:red;
            }
            td{ border: 1px solid black; }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
     <table id="table" style="width: 100%; font-size: 14px;">      
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The Arrat1's values are the first row.
The other rows divided to 4 columns,
Under each Array1's vars appear all array2's vars - if their attribute : "array1" equals to Array1's var name.
The same with Array3:
Neer each Array2's vars appear all array3's vars - if their attribute : "array2" equals to Array2's var name.

But I don't get a good result - not like the first picture.

Comment: In the image, what kind of pattern/order are those alphanumerics in?

Comment: Those alphanumerics are the arrays's vars. Each array has the vars :a,b,c,d... and to each variable in the array I add his array's index. For example : Array1: {a1,b1,c1...}, Array2:{a2,b2...}.
Do you have any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: So that image includes all the values and exactly how they should be displayed?

Comment: The image is only example, I have different arrays with different values (dynamic),I just want to know how to build a table depending on the conditions I wrote up. Thanks!!!